# Passing Parameters through JSP Include and JSP Params Security Issue

Tags: jsp, security, servlets, jsp-tags

This is an issue related to: http://michael-coates.blogspot.com/2010/09/danger-of-jsp-includes-and-parameter.html

TLDR: For those not familiar to the issue, if you decide to render a subview with params passed in through the parent view using jsp:include and jsp:param and the params are not named correctly and you reference a parameter name that does not exist, it is possible for the client to load the page with ?name= or ?value= (whatever the name of your parameter is) and override the value of that variable from the URL and thus control the content you display on the subview.

At the company I work for, we recently experience something very similar to the issue, except we are currently defining the value of the parameter that we pass to the subview.

After hours of digging around:
Understood problem.
Understood what we have currently.
Understood solution.
After trying to debug it in JSP for 30 minutes, I realized don’t understand why…

Here are segments of the code:

We have 2 ViewModels: a SelectorViewModel (for the entire selector) which returns a list of tabs and a TabViewModel (for a specific tab in the selector) which return the value of Name for our particular tab. After debugging, displayName is a truthy String (non null, non empty) in all cases.

```
return new SimpleViewModel(VIEW_NAME, new SelectorViewModel() {
    @Override
    public List<TabViewModel> getListOfTabs() {
        return tabViewModels;
    }
    ...
}

TabViewModels.add(new TabViewModel() {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return tab.getDisplayName();
    }
...
}
```

We use the values in our JSP and pass it to a subview.
(Selector.jsp)

```
<c:forEach items="${component.listOfTabs}" var="tab" >
    <jsp:include page="Tab.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="name" value="${tab.name}"/>
    </jsp:include>
    ...
```

In the Subview (Tab.jsp), we just render param:

```
<a:text cssClass="tab-text">${param.name}</a:text>
```

I can't think of any reason why we are still subject to the security flaw explained above, but when our customers visit our production site, someone shared a link saying: ?name=blah&imageUrl=... and it replaces each tab on our selector with the name and image contents specified in the URL.

One of our senior engineers was assigned to work on this issue and cannot explain why this happens, but he fixed it by passing parameters using the include tag (instead of JSP:include) and passed variables using the page scope to the subview, so now the issue no longer happens in production.

Is this the best fix? Why does this happen? I feel like there is a deeper problem or something we don't fully understand.

Upvote and AC for anyone that can help :)